# How to pack a hard drive

Tags: hard-drive, transporting

I need to take a hard drive on a 3hr car drive tomorrow, and I don't have any antistatic bags/bubblewrap.

**What's the best way to pack an hard drive for a car trip without antistatic bags/bubblewrap so it doesn't break?**

Comment: Why don't you just buy bubble wrap? It is crazy cheap and can be bought at most post or department stores.

Comment: I never had to do this without an anti-static bag or the box a hard drive came in, but I will either put it on the back seat floor or toward the front of the trunk.  That way if I have to hit the brakes the hard drive wouldn't go flying around and hit the dash, back of the seat or the back of my head.

Comment: @joshhunt - Yeah, I could have.  But it's pretty hard to get antistatic bubblewrap at post offices (I've tried).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Wrap some rubber bands around it and then put it in a sock and then wrap it in a towel.  You may want to destatic the towel and sock using [this](http://www.ehow.com/how_4451645_remove-static-electricity-from-fabrics.html) method

Make sure you secure it (like in the dashboard compartment).  And don't crash.

Comment: clever "destatic"-ing technique, but it uses a mixture of water & liquid fabric softener.  i wouldn't recommend either around any computer components.

Comment: Why the rubber bands?

Comment: well, you put only a little on it.  And it stays destaticked even after the liquid dries (evaporates)

Comment: and the residue/fumes from the fabric softener stays around too.  no, thank you.

Comment: Also, this entire method is if you need to be VERY careful (like a fragile old hard drive).  Rubber bands give it a little bit more protection from both static and impact.

Comment: Fabric softener has an anti-static agent in it (no idea how it works chemically) to prevent clothes clinging out of the dryer. In my experience a dilute solution of it doesn't leave any noticeable residue. If you're worried, you could wait until the fabric softener dries and then wipe it with a damp cloth. fwiw, I have heard several anecdotes about using fabric softener to clean tech workbenches.

Answer (score 2):

Wrapping it in newspaper or bubble-wrap inside a box should be fine.

Comment: This was actually what I did.  The drive was okay; my lil bro tried it out and it worked fine in his Xbox.

Answer (score 1):

If you wrap the drive and then cushion it in a briefcase and store it so it can't slide off the seat it should be fine.

For further travel arrangements you may consider the **Fortress Ultra-Rugged Hard Drive**:

[image]

**Safeguard your data from a drop-height of 7 feet onto concrete!**

Something I must get myself now after the '"Big Freeze" in Ireland!

[image]

Comment: lol.  I drop my data from 8 feet on a regular basis, so I guess this not good enough for me.

Comment: be nice to your data!! :P